# What SuspiciousOperationException means on Httpd Server?

Tags: laravel, symfony

I'm using a tool to monitor my application and noticed a routine error log with this exception. I would like to understand what the problem is.

After some research I found an error related to nginx configuration but this project uses apache as http server.

This are some information about my server.

`Linux 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 18 16:35:19 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

That's the exception message.

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Exception\SuspiciousOperationExceptionPOST /
Invalid method override "__CONSTRUCT".
```